# Importing to mySQL causes blank space to convert to 'Â'

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, character-encoding

When I import a table of descriptions any extra spaces beyond the first convert into Â symbols in the database. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Look up MySQL table character encoding.

Comment: Can you give an code example? How do you "import" the table into mysql?

Comment: I have fixed the problem but can't answer my own question for 7 more hours... just set my alarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following MySQL query fixed the problem.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase CHARACTER SET utf8;
```